# Comparing pandas dataframe column with String resulting in False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare dataframe column id with string value contract number

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ee123-abc"
    }
]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
contract_num = 'ee123-abc'

if (df.id == contract_num).any():
    print("Matching")
else:
    print("Not matching")
```

I tried converting `df.c_w_id.astype(str)`, but still the if condition goes to Not Matching. Please advise how to compare a dataframe column with String value.

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: please provide fully reproducible python objects, it will be impossible to debug your code otherwise

Comment: See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for help on how to create a [mcve] so that we can better understand your question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question with sample code.

Comment: @G.Anderson incorrect, Series == scalar will broadcast and produce a Series

Comment: @vvazza your code already works. I get 'Matching'

Comment: I also get a matching value, but you can also try `df.iloc[0,0]` to pull the exact string.

Comment: I tried comparing them, it resulted in False ```>>> df.id == contract_num
0    False
Name: id, dtype: bool```

Comment: @G.Anderson - The code actually failed with the error message -```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()```

Comment: In the sample you provided, the result is a match because, as @mozway very correctly pointed out, the contract number produces a true when it is encountered in the first row and `any()` is therefore true. However, if the actual df values don't match the string exactly (e.g., leading or trailing whitespace, it's part of a larger string, etc) then you would need `df['id'].str.contains(contract_num)` instead

Comment: Thank you ! ```df.id.str.contains(contract_num).any()``` did work. But in the next step, I am trying to fetch the matching row using ```df[df.id == contract_num]``` which results in empty value.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

json = [
    {
        "id": "ee123-abc"
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(json)

contract_num = 'ee123-abc'

print(df)
>>> [{'id': 'ee123-abc'}]
```

This is the condition you need:

```
print(not df[df['id'] == contract_num].empty)
>>> True
```

Therefore:

```
if not df[df['id'] == contract_num].empty:
    print("Matching")
else:
    print("Not matching")
```

I hope it helps :)